# Ошибка при выполнении команды php composer.phar install

Tags: php, ubuntu, composer, symfony3, redis

```
Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache

[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]                                                                       
Warning: Declaration of Snc\RedisBundle\Client\Phpredis\Client::append() should be compatible with Redis::append($key, $value)  

Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-install-cmd event terminated with an exception

[RuntimeException]                                      
An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --n  o-warmup'" command:                                                                                 

[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]                                           

Warning: Declaration of Snc\RedisBundle\Client\Phpredis\Client::append() should be compatible with Redis::append($key, $value)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тому виной особенности реализации `Snc\RedisBundle`:

```
public function append()
{
    return $this->call('append', func_get_args());
}
```

Эта реализация не соблюдает сигнатуру методов, проксируя вызовы с помощью `func_get_args`.

В то же время `PHP Redis`, начиная с версии 4.0 изменил сигнатуры методов.

Вы можете либо найти/дождаться более корректную реализацию,
либо откатить версию `PHP Redis` до 3.1.x,
либо попробовать отключить уровень предупреждений:

```
error_reporting(error_reporting() & ~E_WARNING & ~E_STRICT)
```

[Github Issue](https://github.com/snc/SncRedisBundle/issues/399)

Comment: Как же найти и установить Redis 3.1.*, если на оф сайте нет таких версий http://download.redis.io/releases/

Comment: Из [pecl](https://pecl.php.net/package/redis), вы смотрите сам redis, а не его php драйвер